# Where did the attribute ICU_EXPIRE_FLAG go from MIMIC-II to MIMIC-III?

Tags: mimic-iii

*MIMIC is an openly available dataset developed by the MIT Lab for Computational Physiology, comprising deidentified health data associated with >40,000 critical care patients. It includes demographics, vital signs, laboratory tests, medications, and more.* - [MIMIC homepage](http://mimic.physionet.org/)

The MIMIC-III database currently provides a `HOSPITAL_EXPIRE_FLAG`. In the MIMIC-II database, a `ICU_EXP_FLG` was also available. Is there a particular explanation why it is not included in the MIMIC-III database?

Comment: In which table `ICU_EXP_FLG` was in MIMIC-II? I can't see it on https://github.com/mimic2/v3.0/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=ICU_EXP_FLG

Comment: it might have been called "icustay_expire_flg"

Comment: I see, the attribute `ICUSTAY_EXPIRE_FLG` was in the `ICUSTAY_DETAIL` table. That'd great indeed to have a similar table for MIMIC-III.

Comment: @SvenVanPoucke I added some basic context; please add more information (like the discussion with Franck) to your question so that it can be answered without referring to comments. If you find the answer on your own, you can post an answer yourself, too! --edit: sorry about the MIMIC paragraph; I just noticed that we already have a tag for that. Sorry. Feel free to delete it if you find it redundant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `ICUSTAY_DETAIL` table was shared by researchers at the Laboratory for Computational Physiology to simplify certain queries on the MIMIC-II database. It is derived from other tables within the database and so does not form part of the 'core' dataset.

`ICU_EXP_FLG` is not included in MIMIC-III database (as of version 1.2) because we have not yet attempted to create derived tables such as `ICUSTAY_DETAIL`. We expect to do this in future and would welcome code contributions from the community (see the MIMIC Code Repository linked from http://mimic.physionet.org/).

Comment: Code for generating the ```ICUSTAY_DETAIL``` table is now available in the MIMIC Code Repository: https://github.com/MIT-LCP/mimic-code/tree/master/demographics/postgres